# Apache Flink - Assign unique id to input

Tags: apache-flink

I am loading a CSV file and transforming every line to a POJO using a custom map function. For my program logic i need for every POJO a unique id from 0 to n (where n the total line numbers). My question is, can i assign a unique id (for example the initial line number) to every POJO using a transformation function? The ideal way would be to get an Iterable in a UDF and increment a variable while iterating through the input tuples, and finally outputting the corresponding POJO. My code currently looks like this:

```
DataSet<MyType> input = env.readCsvFile("/path/file.csv")
  .includeFields("1111")
  .types(String.class, Double.class, Double.class,Double.class)
  .map(new ParseData());
```

where ParseData transforms Tuples to the MyType POJOs.

Are there any best practices for achieving this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tricky part is, that you run the code in a distributed system, thus the parallel instances of your `ParseData` function are running independently from each other.

You can still assign unique IDs by using a local ID-counter in `ParseData`. The trick to avoid duplicates is the correct initialization and counter incrementation. Assume you have a parallelism of four, you would get four `ParseData` instances (let's call them `PD1 ... PD4`). You would do the following ID assignments:

```
PD1: 0, 4, 8, 12, ...
PD2: 1, 5, 9, 13, ...
PD3, 2, 6, 10, 14, ...
PD4: 3, 7, 11, 15, ...
```

You can accomplish this, by initializing the parallel instances with different values (details below) and increment the count in each instance by your parallelism (ie, `ID += parallelism`).

In Flink, all instanced of a parallel function get a unique number assigned (so-called *task index*) automatically. You can just use this number to initialize your ID counter. You can get the task index via `RuntimeContext.getIndexOfThisSubtask()`. You can also receive the operator/function parallelism via `RuntimeContext.getNumberOfParallelSubtasks()`

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/RuntimeContext.html

To get the `RuntimeContext` use a `RichMapFunction` to implement `ParseData` and call `getRuntimeContext()` in `open()`.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/RichFunction.html

Something like this (only show relevant methods):

```java
class ParseDate extends RichMapFunction {
    private long parallelism;
    private long idCounter;

    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        RuntimeContext ctx = getRuntimeContext();
        parallelism = ctx.getNumberOfParallelSubtasks();
        idCounter = ctx.getIndexOfThisSubtask();
    }

    public OutputDataType map(InputDataType value) {
        OutputDataType output = new OutputDataType();
        output.setID(idCounter);
        idCounter += parallelism;
        // further processing
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked out for me. I had to add `public void open(Configuration parameters)` for it to work. However, this way the last IDs are not continuous (during every run they are assigned differently), but i guess this has to do with the number of elements assigned to each instance.

Comment: Fixed the open method in my answer -- thanks for pointing it out.
And yes, if data is not distributed equally , you might not get consecutive ID which would be very hard, as you would need a shared global state (which might hit your performance hard). I overlooked this detail in your question.

Comment: What happens if a job crashes? Won't the counter be reinitialized?